# Accessing Remote Blob Storage using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql, rbs

In my SQL server database I have a table with "AllDocStreams" where in the field "Content" some documents are stored as BLOBS. However, some document entries do not have a "Content" entry but rather a "RbsId" (Remote Blob Storage Id) entry. I want to read these blobs via SQL, but do not know and cannot find how to use this RbsId to get the blobs.

If it's any use: for SQL queries I'm using ODBC in R (using the package RODBC)

Do you have any advice on how I can do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is unsupported to query SharePoint databases directly.  You should be accessing the data via the existing supported methods (CSOM/JSOM/REST/etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm aware - but that's not an option for me right now due to time and skill restraints. I'm only doing some analyses on a copy of the database, so there's no real (production) risk in doing this via SQL.

Comment: Why not do some analysis with the correct APIs in the first place?

Comment: Time and skill restraints: I do have experience with SQL, but not with SharePoint (or CSOM/JSOM/REST for that matter), and I got a copy from the database so it seemed like the easiest way to get the data out - up until now it was going smoothly.

Comment: If you’re not going down the supported route, you’re going to find it very difficult to get any answers as no one who works with a production SharePoint environment would even consider doing this.